How do I get the type of an attribute type in Roslyn code generator?
I have a record and an attribute Map<A,B>(Type C, Type D) like so:
[Map<A, B>(Type c, Type d)]
public record MyRecord{}

The somewhere in the Roslyn code generator I'd like to get type type of A or C.
How?

I have a Roslyn code generator like so:
public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
{
var mapSyntaxProvider = context.SyntaxProvider
    .CreateSyntaxProvider(
        predicate: (node, _) => node is RecordDeclarationSyntax { AttributeLists.Count: >= 1 },
    transform: (ctx, _) =>
    {
        return (RecordDeclarationSyntax)ctx.Node;
    })
    .Where(static rds => rds is not null);

    context.RegisterSourceOutput(
        mapSyntaxProvider,
        static (spc, syntax) => ExecuteMapRecord(spc, syntax));
}

private static void ExecuteMapRecord(
    SourceProductionContext spc, 
    RecordDeclarationSyntax syntax)
{
    ...
}

Now somehwere down the line in ExecuteMapRecord, declared above, I'd like to get to A or c.

Solved by trial and horror.
First I have to get to the semantic model, as it will be needed later.
Return both the node as earlier, and the semantic model, from the Initialize method.
    transform: (ctx, _) =>
    {
        var semanticModel = ctx.SemanticModel;
        return (SemanticModel: semanticModel, Node: (RecordDeclarationSyntax)ctx.Node);
    })

Adapt the call to `ExcecuteMapRecord
        context.RegisterSourceOutput(mapSyntaxProvider,
            static (spc, x) => ExecuteMapRecord(spc, x.SemanticModel, x.Node));

Then adapt the ExecuteMapReord itself
private static void ExecuteMapRecord(
    SourceProductionContext spc, 
    SemanticModel semanticModel, 
    RecordDeclarationSyntax syntax)
{
    ...

That was the easy part.
Then, in my ExecuteMapRecord method, comes some code to get to the Attribute. My code does not allow itself for print here, but somehow I manage to get to a  AttributeArgumentSyntax which I convert to a AttributeSyntax through var attribute = attributeData.First().sourceType.FirstAncestorOrSelf<AttributeSyntax>(),
which I still haven't grokked.
Then I check for some sort of GenericNameSyntaxto finally get a list to the final list.
if (attribute.Name is GenericNameSyntax genericNameSyntax)
{
    var typeArguments = genericNameSyntax.TypeArgumentList.Arguments;
    var arg1 = typeArguments[0];
    var arg2 = typeArguments[1];

FWIW. Hopefully someone with more knowledge than I will come by and write a better explanation.
